# #include in header and in main file (c++)

Tags: c++, c, header, include

I have a project where there is a class `item` in a header `item.h`. I need to use the `item` class in both my `main.cpp` file and my `player.h` header.

There are example files to explain my situation :

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "player.h"
#include "item.h"
#include <vector>

std::vector<Item> items;

int main(){
    Item i;
    Player p;
    p.move(10);
    i.ID = 10;
    return 0;
};
```

`player.h`:

```
#include "item.h"
#include <vector>

class Player{
    public:
        std::vector<Item> inventory;
        int x;
        void move(int i){x += i};
};
```

`item.h`:

```
#include <string>

class Item{
    public:
        int ID;
        std::string name;
};
```

It may contain errors as I didn't compiled it, and just wrote it for you to understand my situation. In my real project, I get errors for redefinition of the Item class. I'm new to C++.

Comment: Look up "include guards" for how to avoid problems when a header is included more than once.

Comment: Take a look at [#pragma once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @thebear8 -- with the caution that `#pragma once` is not standard C++ and cannot be implemented correctly on some build platforms. Which is why the usual include guards aren't going to go away.

Comment: @PeteBecker Absolutely. Include guards are the portable way of doing it, however, [just about any compiler nowadays supports it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability) and it seems very unlikely the op is working on platform that does not support it.

Comment: How this question is related to C? Don't spam tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in `item.h`:

```
#ifndef SOME_WORD
#define SOME_WORD // the same as above
//item.h content
#endif
```

You can now import `item.h` in all the files that you want.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you seek is `Include Guards`.

'Include guards' prevent the inclusion of a header file more than once.
If a file is included multiple times you will get an error because you are defining the content of the file multiple times.

In your case using `include guards` in `item.h` will fix your error, but it is recommended to use it in all `.h` files.

An example of how the compilers process you includes:

You got an header file `foo.h`:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo(){
}

#endif // FOO_H
```

In your main file (`main.c`), you include `file.h`:

```
#include "foo.h"

void main() {
    foo();
}
```

After the linking process the compiler would generate the following file:

```
void foo(){
}

void main() {
    foo();
}
```

The compiler took all of the `.h` and `.c` files and stitched them together into one file.

If there was another header file (e.g. `bar.h`) that includes `foo.h` and `main.c` also includes `bar.h`, main will include `foo.h` directly but also through `bar.h`, so `foo` function would be declared twice!

Luckily in this example `foo.h` has `header guards` which practically means `foo.h` cannot be included more than once.

I recommend reading about the preprocessor and specifically about `define`.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-define-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-170